# Rails Ajax image upload not shown with cloudinary

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i am using Cloudinary gem + carrierwave + JqueryFileUpload to configure an ajax display image once it is uploaded.it is working if i save the image to local folder (asset/images) but not with cloudinary.

with Ajax, the image is shown immediately with the image src loaded (through partial render), but with cloudinary, the src is not fetched with Ajax resulting in blank image uploaded. i will need to reload the page in order to see the uploaded image.

please advise or request specific codes to post for you all to assist on this.

thanks.